# I need help trying to blank a cd

Tags: burning, brasero, wodim

I am trying to blank a cd. Sorry in advance for bad formatting, first time user. Also, please ELI5 so I don't have any stupid problems. I first tried it with this code: `umount /dev/cdrom`

`cdrecord dev=/dev/cdrom blank=fast`

And my terminal said:

```
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.  
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identification : 'DVD+-RW GH50N   '
Revision       : 'B104'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc DVD-R(W) driver (mmc_mdvd).
Driver flags   : SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: PACKET SAO
Speed set to 11080 KB/s
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed   8.0 in real BLANK mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    0 seconds. Operation starts.  
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), blank unit scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  A1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
    Sense Bytes: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0A A1 00 00 0E 30 05 00 00
    Sense Key: 0x5 Illegal Request, Segment 0 
    Sense Code: 0x30 Qual 0x05 (cannot write medium - incompatible format)              Fru 0x0
    Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
    cmd finished after 0.009s timeout 9600s
    wodim: Cannot blank disk, aborting.
    wodim: Some drives do not support all blank types.
    wodim: Try again with wodim blank=all.

After this, I tried brasero. I went to the blank section, and it selected my disc, but the "blank" button was a lighter shade and clicking on it did nothing.

Again, sorry for bad formatting, and please explain everything to me like I'm five.

Comment: This is a CD-RW disc right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to blank a rewritable CD-ROM try this instead:

```
wodim dev=/dev/cdrom blank=fast
```

Make sure that you have the correct device name before attempting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the burn software but between drive
and medium. Best guess is that the medium type is not
blankable or that the drive cannot write to that media type.

You can inquire the medium type by

```
wodim -v dev=/dev/cdrom -atip 2>/dev/null | grep '^Current:'
```

(This lengthy shell command drops all error messages and
filters the output messages for a line which begins by the
text "Current:". Without the extras you get 50+ lines of
output which you'd have to search for the line of interest.
See man 1 bash and man 1 grep. (Lengthy reads.))

It should say

```
Current: 0x000A (CD-RW)
```

not

```
Current: 0x0009 (CD-R)
```

Even with command "cdrecord" you actually ran "wodim". See its messages.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas